# Sandbox tool on OpenSUSE with operation not permited

Tags: linux, sandbox, selinux

I have installed Se Linux on my OpenSUSE 11.3 system. All configuration are correct.

When I use the sandbox tool:

```
> LANG=C sandbox -X -H sehome -T tmp -t sandbox_web_t firefox
/usr/bin/chcon: failed to change context of `.sandboxrc' to `user_u:object_r:sandbox_web_file_t:s0:c178,c402': Invalid argument
/usr/bin/chcon: failed to change context of `.xmodmap' to `user_u:object_r:sandbox_web_file_t:s0:c178,c402': Invalid argument
/usr/bin/chcon: failed to change context of `sehome' to `user_u:object_r:sandbox_web_file_t:s0:c178,c402': Invalid argument
/usr/bin/chcon: failed to change context of `tmp' to `user_u:object_r:sandbox_web_file_t:s0:c178,c402': Invalid argument
Failed to unshare: Operation not permitted
```

Has anybody got some suggestions? Maybe adding some new rules to SeLinux?

Answer (score 1):

It's an internal error of the binary chcon, not security errors.
You can try to debug this command like another by using strace, and more .